# Filmstrip Style Image Gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to figure out how to create an image gallery like the one illustrated below so I can place it onto my website. I am wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction for a tutorial? I have found a lot of nice galleries that will display my images, but none of them displays the images like in the filmstrip style I am after.

Requirements of gallery:

1. When clicking on the arrows, the gallery strip will either shift
   left/right by one picture
2. Hovering over the image will darken the image, and display some
   caption about the image

[image: example of filmstrip style gallery]

Comment: First SO question that's ever made me hungry.

Comment: @Michael Thank you. I wish I can take the credit for the gorgeous photos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just answered a question where someone was using [carouFredSel](http://caroufredsel.frebsite.nl/). This jQuery plugin looks like it would work pretty well, though I do not think it has the built-in hover effect. To be honest though, that is the easier part.

The trick is to make the width slightly larger than the images to show, which leads to the partial images on each side.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6mj4N/7/) to illustrate.

---

**UPDATE:**
The OP asked if the page nav links could be repositioned. I modified the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6mj4N/10/) to work this way. The additions were as follows:

```
.list_carousel {
    position: relative;
}
#prev2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    left: 0;
}
#next2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    right: 0;
}
```

If you have a relatively positioned container element, you can absolutely position child elements. I added relative positioning to the `list_carousel` container, then I could absolutely position the nav arrows within the container. Change the `top` value to position vertically, and left/right to position horizontally.

I also removed the pager all together, as it was not a requirement based on the original example. If you change the page arrows to images it is pretty much what you want.

---

**MORE UPDATES**
I decided to take it one step further and make the `hover` effect work more like the example. See the new [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6mj4N/11/). The changes are:

- Added span wrappers around all text within list items
- Added `$(".list_carousel li span").hide();` to hide all the spans
- Modified hover event to toggle spans

I also added some CSS to position the span text:

```
.list_carousel li { 
    position: relative;
}
.list_carousel li span {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

---

**FINAL UPDATE (I PROMISE!)**
I decided to go all in and add the transparency layer too: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6mj4N/13/)

Hover modifications:
`$(this).prepend($("<div class='hover-transparency'></div>"));` and `$(this).find("div:first").remove();` to add/remove transparency layer on hover in/out.

CSS modifications:

```
.hover-transparency {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.60);
}
```

These style the transparency layer. Change to suit your taste.

Comment: +1 Excellent fiddle and the **carouFredSel** is a great recommendation too.

Comment: Thank you jesus.tesh. I am wondering if it is possible to move the arrows and page so that they are on top of the photos? I tried `margin:-40 0 0 0; z-index:1000` but I could not see the page numbers, and cannot click on the arrows.

Comment: @Jon - I think the arrows and page numbers were left over from the previous question. I'll "fiddle" a bit and see what I can come up with :)

Comment: Thank you jesus.tesh for your hard work! That is exactly what I am looking for :)

Comment: @Jon - You are welcome. I had a lot of fun figuring it out, and best of all it helps you out :)

Comment: Sorry, I also have one more issue. I just noticed that when I set `width:100%` for the carousel, there would be a small strip of background peeking out on the side. Also, when I would resize the browser, the background strip would grow horizontally. To fix this, I called the carouFredSel() function multiple times, but seemed to not make both forward/backword arrows not work properly.

Comment: Link to original where the background strip is peeking: http://www.sfu.ca/~jca41/stuph/carouFredSel-5.6.1/broken.html . Link to my modified version where I attempted to fix my problem: http://www.sfu.ca/~jca41/stuph/carouFredSel-5.6.1/broken2.html

Comment: @Jon - if you set the container to `width: 100%;` then it **will** grow in width as you resize. If you do not wish that to happen, you have to set the container to a fixed width. It is probably the cause of your "peeking" too. "100% wide" may be, say, `755px`, but you explicitly set the width to `750px` for the plugin. That would leave `5px` unaccounted for. Of course, this is just a guess without seeing your code.

Comment: Ok, looked at the code - it looks like it is the width you specify in the plugin. Change it to 100%.

Comment: Did you mean to change to change `width:winW` to `width:100%` on line 40 in http://www.sfu.ca/~jca41/stuph/carouFredSel-5.6.1/broken.html? When I did so, the script broke and console reported the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12474/discussion-between-jesus-tesh-and-jon)

Answer (score 0):

Something like [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/) should do the trick.  Once you have the carousel functionality in place, you can add in the hover affect via CSS and a span that contains the caption.

Answer (score 0):

I was just looking at [**ContentFlow Plugin**](http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/index.php) which is JavaScript based.

They include a separate library of additional plugin you can use that takes care of your Slideshow requirements, in particularity this one [**HERE**](http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/addons.php#ContentFlow_carousel). When you use the mousewheel over the 3 images, it scrolls by 1. That said, you can mod the plugin to do the same when the arrow buttons are clicked.

Sample plugin markup looks like:

```
{
  shownItems: 3,    //number of visible items
  showCaption: true // show item caption
  width: 100,       // relative item width
  height: 100,      // relative item height
  space: 0.4        // relative item spacing
}
```

To address that the captions should be visible only on mouse hover, I would set showCaption to always be true along with using a jQuery `.hover();` Event Listener that will use `.show();` and `.hide();` on the caption Class Name `.caption` when required. Also, using jQuery to set the opacity can be done within the `.hover();` event too.

The latest version of **ContentFlow v1.0.2** supports multiple instances on the same webpage if that's ever required.